# Validate each value in PSCustomObject - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having a bit of trouble making something that may be rather easy to make but I'm not finding the path.

I'm trying to make a verifier PSCustomObject to validate multiple input from the whole program so at the end it enables a button (has wpf interface).

Right now I'm using an IF statement with multiple conditions (one for each property in the verifier object) to check if all verifications are true, but is taking quite the length in the script.

Here's an example of what I have now:

```
PSCustomObject]$verifier = @{
  'Item1' = $false
  'Item2' = $false
  'Item3' = $false
  'Item4' = $false
  'Item5' = $false
}

*code where users modifies the input that alters the items in the pscustomobject*

if(($verifier.Item1) -and ($verifier.Item2) -and ($verifier.Item3) -and ($verifier.Item4) -and ($verifier.Item5)){
  *enable the button*
}
else{
  *graphically show the user the wrong/missing input*
}
```

Is there any way to make that IF statement simpler? Tried using foreach but it's verifying all values at the same time instead of evaluating each one.
I want the condition to return true when all are true and false when any ammount of values are false, and recover those that are false.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to make that IF statement simpler?

Definitely, use a [containment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators):

```
$verifier = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'Item1' = $true
    'Item2' = $true
    'Item3' = $true
    'Item4' = $true
    'Item5' = $true
}

if($verifier.PSObject.Properties.Value -notcontains $false) {
    'enable the button'
}
else {
    'graphically show the user the wrong/missing input'
}
```

You can access the values of all properties via [`PSObject` intrinsic member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#object-views).

---

**Note:** There is a clear distinction between `$verifier = [PSCustomObject]@{` and `[PSCustomObject] $verifier = @{`, the former will return a custom object while the latter will return a hashtable. The [`[pscustomobject]` type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7.3#creating-a-pscustomobject) **only works when casting to a hashtable, not when constraining your variable**.

If you want to use a hashtable instead of a PSCustomObject, then call the [`.Values` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.3#displaying-hashtables) from it:

```
$verifier = @{
    'Item1' = $true
    'Item2' = $true
    'Item3' = $true
    'Item4' = $true
    'Item5' = $true
}

if($verifier.Values -notcontains $false) {
    'enable the button'
}
else {
    'graphically show the user the wrong/missing input'
}
```

Comment: So I tested the method but when i turn them all true it still returns that some are false, any idea?

Comment: 'False
False
False
Item2
Item4
Item5
Item3
Item1
True
True
True
True
True
System.Object
5'
This is what the variable prints if i run it, there are 3 more false items

Comment: @FrancoCanciani the example provided in this answer will return `enable the button` since all are true so I'm not sure. Perhaps `$verifier` in your code is not actually a PSCustomObject and something to which you would need to clarify.

Comment: @FrancoCanciani nevermind, I noticed you're doing `[PSCustomObject] $verifier =` instead of `$verifier = [PSCustomObject]@{` that is a hashtable not a custom object. The accelerator only works when its casted to a hashtable. I'll clarify in my answer

Comment: Actually, yes, I noticed it too, my bad! Now it's working properly, but how can I return the values that are false?

Comment: @FrancoCanciani not part of your initial question but you just need to filter `$verifier.PSObject.Properties | ? { -not $_.Value }`

Comment: Perfect! I suposed a Where-Object would do the trick, thanks a lot! I'll mark your answer to solve the case